# Parcelable replacing field object's values?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I'm sending `Parcelable` object in `ArrayList<Contact>` from Activity1 to Activity2.

Before I actually send object to Activity2, I do simple `Log.i()` function. It prints out this:

```
I/String representation from Activity1: Contact{id=1, firstName='John', lastName='Doe', email='john@gmail.com', photoPath='/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20200502-094346__02.jpg', note='some notes'}
```

In Activity2, it prints out this:

```
I/String representation from Activity2: Contact{id=6, firstName='1', lastName='John', email='Doe', photoPath='john@gmail.com', note='/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_20200502-094346__02.jpg'}
```

Object is completely messed up. There's no possibility for id to be 6 since I have only one object in db. For other fields you can see it yourself.

Finally, here is complete `Contact` class:

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable{

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("firstName")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("lastName")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("photoPath")
    @Expose
    private String photoPath;

    @SerializedName("note")
    @Expose
    private String note;


    public Contact(){
        //photoPath = "";
    }

    public Contact(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String photoPath, String note) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.photoPath = photoPath;
        this.note = note;
    }

    protected Contact(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        firstName = in.readString();
        lastName = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
        photoPath = in.readString();
        note = in.readString();

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhotoPath() {
        return photoPath;
    }

    public void setPhotoPath(String photoPath) {
        this.photoPath = photoPath;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public String getPhotoFilename() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        // Log.i("timestampe", timeStamp);
        return "IMG_" + getId() + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeStringArray(new String[]{this.id.toString(), this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.photoPath, this.note});

        /*dest.writeString(this.id.toString());
        dest.writeString(this.firstName);
        dest.writeString(this.lastName);
        dest.writeString(this.email);
        dest.writeString(this.photoPath);
        dest.writeString(this.note);*/
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Contact> CREATOR= new Parcelable.Creator<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Contact(source);  //using parcelable constructor
        }

        @Override
        public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Contact[size];
        }

    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", photoPath='" + photoPath + '\'' +
                ", note='" + note + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I've tried both options `from writeToParcel()`, non worked.

Comment: Neither of your `writeToParcel` match your `Contact(Parcel in)` constructor. Where do you `writeInt()` to match your `readInt()`?

Comment: Ah, I think I got. In  protected Contact(Parcel in)  there should be  id = in.readInt() and in writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) there should be dest.writeInt(this.id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `writeToParcel()` needs to exactly match what your `Contact(Parcel in)` does: if you are using `readInt()`, you need to use `writeInt()` in the exact same order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ian, I did like you suggested in comment. It works now. Thank you :)

```
protected Contact(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    firstName = in.readString();
    lastName = in.readString();
    email = in.readString();
    photoPath = in.readString();
    note = in.readString();
}


 @Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.firstName);
    dest.writeString(this.lastName);
    dest.writeString(this.email);
    dest.writeString(this.photoPath);
    dest.writeString(this.note);
}
```